# TAB effect upon Hitting ENTER key in VC6-MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I would like to implement the TAB effect on multiple textboxes. Upon entering a value in a textbox and then hitting the enter key, the focus should automatically be moved to the next textbox (same as pressing the TAB key with focus in the textbox). Currently I am trying to use this piece of code in PreTranslateMessage():

```
if ( (pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN) )
{
   if( m_CeditCtrlLlaLatDegrees.GetFocus() )
    {
          keybd_event( VK_TAB,0x09,0,0);
         // keybd_event( VK_TAB,0x09,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

    }
}
```

The above code pushes the focus onto the textbox following the next immediate textbox (i.e. 
it moves 2 tabs ahead) There are 20 textboxes all taken from CEdit and all accept only numeric values.

How do I retrieve the ID for each of these textboxes? I tried assigning CEdit (control variable) and accessing the ID for each textbox, then through a switch-case statement I would check which textbox is active and then SetFocus() to the next immediate one (all of this in PreTranslateMessage()). But even this won't work.

Please suggest a way to get this to work. Please let me know the flow/code in detail since I am a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

This should accomplish what you want:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg )
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN)
    {
        CWnd* pFocus = GetFocus();
        if (pFocus && pFocus->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit)))
        {
            NextDlgCtrl();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }


    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ....sorry for replying late ..will implement this and get back ...thanks again